# jQuery calculating height incorrectly after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

i'm using jQuery to vertically center different elements on a page. I wont be able to use the table-cell css-statement, because it's not supported in lower versions of IE, so i'm using jQuery to calculte half of the height and then set it in the middle via negative margin.

This works fine if i just use the adressbar to refresh the page, but if i'm using the reload-button it will calculate the wrong height and set it way too low.
For example, the height of the broken element is 863px but jQuery sets margin-top: -228.5px;

Thanks in advance.

```
function verticalCenter(object) {
    objectHeight = $(object).height() / -2;
    $(object).css({'position':'relative','top':'50%','marginTop':objectHeight});
}   

$( document ).ready(function() {
    verticalCenter("#promo-heading");
    verticalCenter("#center1");
    verticalCenter("#center2");
});
```

Comment: Maybe try $(window).load ( function() {}); rather than document.

Comment: What is the content of these elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is any image content on `document.ready` is not downloaded, and height will be changed after that. Try to use:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it - it was about the images. Thanks a lot!